# conflicts within mvc:annotation-driven in dispatcher servlet configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ant, websocket, atmosphere

I was trying to integrate an atmosphere websockets maven project to a spring ant project. But while configuring, it seems to be some conflicts are raised in bean instantiation.

This is my dispatcher-servlet

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean class="com.project.AtmosphereArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

This is the error shown:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource]: Specified class is an interface

Comment: what conflicts are arised in bean instantiation? Post exception stacktrace

Comment: I don't know what exactly is. It says BeanInstantiationException... This is the error shown:     

    Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource]: Specified class is an interface

Comment: I'm facing this: [cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'mvc:annotation-driven' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.], any suggestions.?

Answer (score -2):

Exactly! `org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource` is an interface so the exception. Spring is trying to instantiate bean `org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource` which should be a class but it's an interface. You can not instantiate interface. You need to provide `org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource`'s implementation class.

Comment: AtmosphereArgumentResolver is my org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource's implementation class... This is the code:...

Comment: Check your configuration for `org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource` other than your posted xml `<beans:bean class="com.project.AtmosphereArgumentResolver" />`

Comment: AtmosphereArgumentResolver is my org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource's implementation class...

Comment: public class AtmosphereArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver{
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter){
        return AtmosphereResource.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());}
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest=webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);  return Meteor.build(httpServletRequest).getAtmosphereResource();}}